# JavaFx KeyPress event doesn't recognize arabic lsnguage characters

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm writing JAVAFX application and assign some key shortcuts that work with English keyboard layout only.
How we can make java recognize character Regardless active keyboard layout?

```
final KeyCombination CONTROL_F = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
    if (CONTROL_F.match(keyEvent)) {
        filterFlatButtonX.fireEvent(new ActionEvent());
    }
```

Comment: Please add an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates what you are doing and what is going wrong.  Note also, that [KeyPress generates KeyCodes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCode--), not characters.  Characters are [generated by KeyTyped events](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter--).

Comment: KeyTyped dosn't recognise Modifire Keys like CONTROL or SHIFT

Comment: Well, as I said, you'll need an mcve to get assistance, and maybe also somebody else with an arabic keyboard.   The sample currently posted is just an "F" which doesn't seem arabic specific to me, so I'm not sure why it would be an issue.

Comment: `final KeyCombination CONTROL_F = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F, 
                KeyCombination.KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN);`

Comment: The problem not in the modifire but in F key